# local variable refrenced before assignment python 3.4

Tags: python

I tryed to use i as a variable and I got this
"Local variable 'i' referenced before assignment" error

I added a global command and it still didn't work

(this code has python packages)

This is the code

```
i=0

global i
from PIL import ImageGrab
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        ImageGrab.grab().save("dones"+str(i)+".png")
        i+=1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    def t():
        d=open("imagepaths.txt","w")
        while True:
            d.write("dones"+str(i)+".jpg")
            if int(i)==0:
                d.close()
                exit()
            else:
                i-=1
                t()
    t()
```

where is the global meant to go?

Comment: Refer to [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `global i` within your `def t()`:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    def t():
        global i # <-- here
        d = open("imagepaths.txt","w")
        ...
```

The `global` keyword only applies within a function.

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced the global keyword. You should place it inside the local scope.

```
def t():
   global i
   # next code
```